# WordPress add_rewrite_rule for a string returning 404

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently working on a WordPress project and am a little stuck on the .htaccess rewrite rules.

My WordPress rewrite rule code is as follows:

```
if (!function_exists('check_string_id_rule')){
function check_string_id_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule('id-check/([^/]+)','id-check/?id=$1','top');
}
add_action('init', 'check_string_id_rule');
```

*Disclaimer: according to the documentation I am supposed to use $matches[1] instead of $1. I've tried that but, it will simply set the value of id to "matches[1]". $1 seems to do the trick, to an extent.*

When I navigate to *mywebsite.com/id-check/12* everything works fine and my id has the value of 12.

My ID's are however built up out of a number of characters containing letters from a-z, numbers from 0-9 and the occasional hyphen '-'.

If I navigate to *mywebsite.com/id-check/12a-5*, I get redirected to an empty page. WordPress appears to redirect me to a page that doesn't exist. It is trying to redirect me to the /12a-5 page. Going to *mywebsite.com/id-check/?id=12-a5* works as intended.

Why is my my rule not being enforced? I checked the .htaccess file and there don't seem to be any competing rules.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^id-check/([^/]+) /id-check/?id=$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is this some WordPress quirk, or am I missing something here?

Thank you in advance,

Stijn van der Pol

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve my own problem. It seems my issue resided in the second parameter of my add_rewrite_rule logic.

I partially followed the following article: http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/

I know hyperlinking is frowned upon, but credits to rlmseo.com. In short they suggested a different approach of registering rewrite rules. With a couple of changes of my own it lead to the following code..

Within my functions.php:

```
if(!function_exists('add_rewrite_rules')){
    function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
        $aNewRules = ['id-check/([^/]+)' => 'index.php?pagename=id-check&id=$matches[1]'];
        $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
        return $aRules;
    }
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

And then I use the following tag rewrite logic in my functions.php as well:

```
function id_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%id%', '([^/]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'id_rewrite_tag');
```

Then in my view I access the variable by using:

```
global $wp_query;
$id = $wp_query->query_vars['id'];
```

I hope this is of help to someone :-)